# WinXP: Changing Default Hotkeys

Tags: hotkeys, keymap

Is there a way to customize the default hotkeys in windows xp? For example, currently win+e opens "My Computer" and win+r opens the run dialog. Is there a way to either change the target of the hotkeys or remap the hotkeys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) is a small but powerful utility that allows you to map hotkeys. Otherwise, you may have to start digging into the registries.

Comment: +1: I can verify that this will let you override the Windoze defaults.

Answer (score 0):

[HotKeyz](http://www.skynergy.com/hotkeyz.html) have the option to disable the windows shortcuts and set your own (including some nice build-in shortcuts like 'volume control' and 'lock & Close monitor' in one key).